# How to shift characters in a String in C?

Tags: c

How can I shift characters in a string to the right?
For Example I want to shift every letter of "Hello" 3 times to the right. The ending letter starts at the beginning. So the output should be "lloHe".

I tried to do it with a pointer. But the output is just "k". The program just takes the "h" from the hello and shifts it 3 digits to the right from the alphabet. But thats not what I intended to do. Any tips you can give me?

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main () {
    int a[5] = {'h','e','l', 'l','o','\0'};
    char i;
    char ptr;

    ptr = a;
    printf ("%c\n",ptr+3);

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: int a[5] has actually 6 characters. What you are looking for is not shifting, rather kind-of rotating.

Comment: No. `a` has 5 characters and a warning about extra initializers.

Comment: @tilz0R thanks for your reminder. Im actually new to c, thats why im a bit "lost". Do you have a website or a thread or similar you can forward me onto?

Answer (score 0):

Do you actually want to manipulate the data, or just produce the output?   You could do something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char a[] = {'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0'};  /* Note the [], and the type */
    char i;
    char *ptr;    /* Note the '*'; ptr is a pointer */

    ptr = a;
    int shift = argc > 1 ? strtol(argv[1], NULL, 10) : 3;

    shift %= sizeof(a);

    printf("%s", ptr + shift);   /* Note the %s */
    fwrite(a, 1, shift, stdout);
    putchar('\n');

    return 0;
}
```

Usually, the initialization would be written `char a[] = "hello";`, and if you make `a` an array of int, you cannot use `printf` to do output.  If you need `a` to be ints for some reason, you could do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int a[] = {'h','e','l', 'l','o','\0'};
    int shift = argc > 1 ? strtol(argv[1], NULL, 10) : 3;
    shift %= sizeof a  / sizeof *a;
    int *ptr = a + shift;

    /* Print the tail of the string */
    while( ptr < a + sizeof a / sizeof *a ){
        putchar(*ptr++);
    }
    /* Print the head of the string */
    ptr = a;
    while( ptr < a + shift ){
        putchar(*ptr++);
    }
    putchar('\n');
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int a[5] = ...
char ptr;
ptr = a;
```

Here `a` [is a pointer to `int`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1461432/509868). Assigning it to a variable of type `char` is not a correct thing to do. Compilers should emit a warning on that. Don't ignore warnings: they usually indicate that there is something wrong in your code!

You probably intended to use `int *` instead of `char`:

```
int a[5] = ...
int *ptr;
ptr = a;
```

With this code, shifting the pointer will work: `ptr+3` does what you want.

---

To print one character at a pointer, dereference the pointer first:

```
printf ("%c\n", *(ptr+3)); // alternative spelling: ptr[3]
```

If you don't dereference, the compiler will warn you that the code is incorrect.